# How to configure the Yii2 UrlManager to handle rules with and without trailing slash

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I have a page like `domain.com/calendar/2001/8/22`, it can be visited by

```
domain.com/calendar/2001
domain.com/calendar/2001/8
domain.com/calendar/2001/8/22
```

It will show different content depending on URL.

I configured the `urlManager` rules:

```
'calendar/<year:[\-\d]+>' => 'calendar/view',
'calendar/<year:[\-\d]+>/<month:[\d]+>' => 'calendar/view',
'calendar/<year:[\-\d]+>/<month:[\d]+>/<day:[\d]+>' => 'calendar/view',
```

It's OK. But when I visit `domain.com/calendar/2008/8/` (with the trailing slash, my website users often visit with trailing slash), I get 404.

How to configure the `urlManager` to handle rules with and without trailing slash?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`UrlNormalizer`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer) to redirect "slash URLs" to "non-slash URLs" (or vice versa):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,,
    'normalizer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlNormalizer',
    ],
],
```

It will redirect all "slash URLs" to "non-slash URLs". If you want to use "slash URLs", you should set [`UrlManager::$suffix`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$suffix-detail) to `/`, then `UrlNormalizer` will redirect "non-slash URLs" to "slash URLs".

You can find more info about normalization in [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-normalization).

Answer (score 0):

Add `'suffix' => '/',` just after `'enablePrettyUrl' => true,`. Be aware that it will change all links on  your site.